# How to write average if formulas between two months, however the month should be general name format not as date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Below is Currently Using Formula to arrive averages as target for the month, In which method we need to change reference manually for all worksheets every month.

Below is basic **Average** formulas for Last 12 Months (May'18 - Apr'19) Which is the target for May'19.

Average Count: 380.75   Formula Used: **AVERAGE(B7:B18)**

Average Amount: 181111.0058   Formula Used **AVERAGE(C7:C18)**

I need new average formula which can take averages between May'18 to Apr'19 months based on General format the months should not be covered as date (or) Month format. It should be as General Text Value.

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Please explain the last part through some sample data with expected results. Right now it's more a guessing game. Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question.

Comment: See now the same has been edited, actually every month we are changing reference manually for Average Function. The same methods applied in multiple worksheet. Need to fix it as based on one sheet reference all sheets have to change and the average should calculated between last 12 month.

Comment: Hi, The same has been answered by Scott. Anyway thanks for your support :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for B:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TEXT(EOMONTH(NOW(),-1),"mmm'yy"),$A:$A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TEXT(EOMONTH(NOW(),-12),"mmm'yy"),$A:$A,0)))
```

and this for C:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TEXT(EOMONTH(NOW(),-1),"mmm'yy"),$A:$A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TEXT(EOMONTH(NOW(),-12),"mmm'yy"),$A:$A,0)))
```

It finds the correct months and sets the range.

[image]

Comment: Really Awesome :-), you're an intelligent.

Comment: Thank lot for the new formula!!